# draw and save an image

Tags: java, io

I'm coding the simple project to draw lines and save likes an image,but when I run, it shows an errors that I can't fix. Please help me.

Here is my **code**:

```
package image;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class paint extends JFrame{
private Point points[] = new Point[10000];
private Point pointends[] = new Point[10000];
private int pointCount = 0;
private JButton save_btn;
public paint()
{
    panel paint2 = new panel();
    add(paint2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
private class panel extends JPanel
{   

    public panel()
    {   
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        save_btn = new JButton();
        save_btn.setText("123");
        this.add(save_btn);
    /*  save btnhandler = new save();
        save_btn.addActionListener(btnhandler);*/
        MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
        this.addMouseMotionListener(handler);

        this.addMouseListener(handler);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int i = 0;i <pointCount;i++)
        {   
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(points[i].x, points[i].y, pointends[i].x, pointends[i].y);
        }           
    }
}

private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter
{  
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pointends[ pointCount-1] = e.getPoint();
            repaint();


    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.mousePressed(e);
//find point
                    if(pointCount < points.length)
        {
            points[ pointCount ] = e.getPoint();//find point
            pointends[ pointCount ] = e.getPoint();
            pointCount++; 
            repaint();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.mouseReleased(e);
        /*pointends[pointCount]=e.getPoint();
        repaint();
        pointCount++;
    */
    }

}

}
```

and the class of save event

```
package image;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.Buffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class save implements ActionListener{

private paint paint1 = new paint();
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter file name: ");
            //
    BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(paint1.getWidth(), paint1.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bufImage, "jpg", new File(str + ".jpg"));
    } catch (IOException ox) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        ox.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}//end class
```

Comment: sorry for syntax errors :(,but don't care about it ,

Comment: _it shows an errors_ what are those errors?

Comment: The syntax errors may be important as with the problematic syntax we may not be able to tell what you were trying to do in correct syntax. Anyway what are the errors? Sự lỗi cú pháp có thể quan trọng như với cú pháp vấn đề chúng tôi có thể không có thể nói gì bạn đã cố gắng thực hiện theo cú pháp chính xác. Các lỗi có ở khắp mọi những gì?

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError" - that is there errors it shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that Your `paint` JFrame creates an instance of your `save` ActionListener, and your `save` ActionListener creates an instance of your `paint` JFrame. Thus you run into an infinite loop of constructors.

Instead of creating a new `paint` object, pass the current one in the constructor for `save`.

```
private paint paint1 = null;
public save(paint panel) {
    this.paint1 = panel;
}
```

Now, in your `panel` constructor, pass a reference to the current instance to the ActionListener:

```
save btnhandler = new save(my_paint);     // see Update below
save_btn.addActionListener(btnhandler);
```

This should fix your immediate problem. However, I recommend restructuring your code a bit, and you should also try to follow Java coding conventions, e.g., using CamelCase names for classes, and using correct indentation. This will make it much easier for others (and yourself) to read and undertand your code.

**Update:** I just realized that your object structure is a bit more complicated... your `paint` JFrame creates a `panel` JPanel, which creates a `save` ActionListener, which again creates a `paint` JFrame. The basic argument and solution remain the same, but instead of using `new save(this)` you have to either pass a reference to the JFrame containing the JPanel, or change the type of the field in your ActionListener.

Alternatively you could make bothe the JPanel and the ActionListener inner classes of the `paint` JFrame. This way you can access the JFrame directly from within the ActionListener and do not have to pass a reference at all, thus circumvent the problem entirely and giving a bit more structure to the code.